# Can read file from android sdcard using java

Tags: java, android, file, audio

When I try to read file from sdcard I get an error source not found.

```
    private void merge2WavFiles(String wavFile1, String wavFile2, String newWavFilePath) {

    try {
        AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
```

I can't get the audio input stream...
Of course the file exists. what could be the problem?

EDIT: The error is source not found (instead of file not found)

Using LogCat I managed to find the error:

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you know the file exists?

Comment: I know it because I create it...
I also can see the file in the device

Comment: Hi, you should be able to delete your own questions if you feel they were asked with the incorrect or not enough information. I'll decline the request to have this question deleted, but if you still need help doing so, please reflag it and a moderator will read my comment and go ahead and delete it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is simple...Android dosen't support the javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem anymore

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) about how to access files on SD card. And [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#STORAGE) about manifest file permissions. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.
I need to merge two audio files together...
Do you know how can I do it?